# Waterproofing Brick foundation

Tags: water, foundation, masonry

I live in a brick house built circa 1975 in northern Alabama.  It has a huge brick/cinder block/concrete front porch. The brick is a veneer that goes around the bottom.  When it rains, some of the water runs along the seam where the brick porch meets the house and down the corner where it soaks the ground beside the wall.  My question is, how would I go about keeping the water from soaking the ground right up against the wall?  I've considered pouring concrete in the corner to move it away, but what other options are there?

Comment: Sealing the masonry may not be the best or first solution. Is the ground properly sloped? Very little water should run to the wall. Do you have rain gutters in that area?

Comment: Yes, there are gutters that keep the rain from the walls of the house.  The problem is the water running off the porch that ends up running down the brick veneer (of the porch) near the foundation. The ground is sloped, but it doesn't help if the water is running down the brick veneer of the porch (if that makes sense).  My thought was dig out two or three inches of dirt by the foundation then pour concrete into that gap then on the sloped dirt.

Comment: So I wouldn't be sealing the masonry as much as I'd be pouring a small bit of concrete in the corner (onto dirt and rock) where the brick porch meets the foundation of the house.

Comment: Why doesn't the porch have gutters? That was sort of my point. The water from every roof plane should be managed appropriately.

Comment: I'm dumb.  I said porch but meant patio.  No roof,  just a large stoop like structure.

Comment: I've tried, site just keeps loading but never fully uploads.  I'll keep trying!